# AIrflow BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator saves CSV file with quotes in each row

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow, export-to-csv

I am using Airflow with BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator operator to save a copy of the BQ table as a CSV file in GCP storage bucket. The source table has just one column, with the content of a few comma separated fields:`a1,b1,c1,d1`. The output file is saved fine, but each row has double quotes at the beginning and at the end:`"a1,b1,c1,d1"`. In the [doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.5/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_to_gcs/index.html) I don't see any parameters to control this behavior, to exclude those double quotes from the output file. Is there a way to fix this? The desired output would be just a string like `a1,b1,c1,d1` , without double quotes at the beginning and at the end of each row.

There is a parameter `quote_character=""` which I thought can help here, when I include it into my DAG in BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator initialization, but it doesn't do anything in my case.

Comment: Which is the separator you chose for the output csv file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you used the `field_delimiter` param with `,` as value (it's the default value in the operator, if it's not specified) :

```py
def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        source_project_dataset_table: str,
        destination_cloud_storage_uris: List[str],
        project_id: Optional[str] = None,
        compression: str = 'NONE',
        export_format: str = 'CSV',
        field_delimiter: str = ','
.....
```

Your single column contains also `,` characters, that's why the `BigQuery` api adds a quote char between the column value.

I tried with a separator different from `,` for example with `|` character and the `csv` file was generated without quote char between the column value :

```bash
bq extract --location=EU \
--destination_format CSV \
--compression NONE \
--field_delimiter "|" \
--print_header=true \
"project:mazlum_test.test_list_column" \
gs://mazlum_dev/test_column_list.csv
```

The result `csv` file with `|` as separator is :

```
my_list
a1,b1,c1,d1
```

The result `csv` file with `,` as separator is :

```
my_list
"a1,b1,c1,d1"
```

With `Airflow`, you only have to set the `field_delimiter` parameter with `|` as value for example :

```py
BigQueryToGCSOperator(
            task_id='task_id',
            source_project_dataset_table='table',
            destination_cloud_storage_uris=[
                'dest_bucket'
            ],
            compression='NONE',
            export_format='CSV',
            field_delimiter="|",
            print_header=True
        )
```

Comment: how to compress file while using BigQueryToGCSOperator , I tried with compression='GZIP' but still its not reducing size of file